# Notebook PC with damaged and removed screen not working as expected with external display connected

Tags: external-display

So, I was trying to reset my Windows 10 PC. Once done I am unable to see the process due to my broken laptop screen. After watching a video, they recommended to snip the display cables and then remove the display panel.

Well I did that and well, it didn't work. So now I have no screen at all and no way to reconnect one. I do have an external monitor, but none of the <kbd>f4</kbd> buttons and stuff work. So basically I need to be able to see the setup process on an external monitor.

Image of computer without screen:

[image: Image of computer without screen.]

Comment: You should take it to the nearest computer repair technician, you have caused irreversible damage to your machine (unless the display is replaced), the permanent damage done to the display cable will prevent you from finishing the installation of Windows.

Comment: post the make & model of laptop so we can understand what you have to work with.  I am not sure but the bios screen may only display on the laptop screen and not on an external displayport or hdmi, but might if there's a vga.

Comment: So, I am trying to understand, “After watching a video, they recommended to snip the display cables and then remove the display panel.” At this point, I would recommend bringing it to a tech to see if you can get them to attach a new display. But I would recommend simply removing the hard drive/SSD/storage to retain your data from this damaged machine and just buy a new machine.

Comment: Damn it, I think I will take it to a tech place near me for now, if they can't do anything I will take out the drive I guess.

Comment: What is so special about this laptop? It looks like a several year old run of the mill consumer model... At this point why bother, just pull the drive(s) and buy a another one. The amount would invest into this is going to 5 times what it's worth in the long run, for the couple hundred bucks it would take to get this semi-functional again, just buy a decent used machine.

Comment: Yeah, I am about to build one soon, I was just gonna turn this into a NAS. I upgraded it's storage to 3 tb and gave it 16 gigs of ram. I thought it would be a good NAS server. For now, I am gonna pull the drive and when I build a new PC I will put it in it.

Comment: Update: Took it to a tech, they said they can't fix it so, I am gonna take the drive out and when I build my new PC I can put this in it. Thanks for everyone's help.